# Scrapy extract from children

Tags: python, extract, scrapy

This is the source code from www.example, com that I want to extract. If anyone can explain what I need to extract.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;padding-left:4px;" class="category"><img-src="http://www.example.com/images/menu.gif">TEXT in td 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="date" colspan="5">TEXT in td 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="test-align:left;width:40px;">TEXT in td 3</td>
        <td style="padding-right:4px; width:180px;text-align:right">TEXT in td 4</td>
        <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"> TEXT in td 5</td>
        <td style="padding-left:5px; width:180px;text-align:left">TEXT in td 6</td>
        <td style="width:40px;text-align:center"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my code that I want to extrract. I want to extract each separate text, 
text 4, 5 and 6 am drawn well. Text 1, 2 and 3 if anyone can tell me how can I extract. Thanks in advance!

```py
    item['TEXT in td 1'] = app.select('//td[2]//text()').extract()
    item['TEXT in td 2'] = app.select('//td[3]/text()').extract()
    item['TEXT in td 3'] = app.select('td[4]/text()').extract()
    item['TEXT in td 5'] = app.select('td[3]//text()').extract()
    item['TEXT in td 4'] = app.select('td[2]/text()').extract()
    item['TEXT in td 6'] = app.select('td[4]/text()').extract()

This a extract Scrapy:

2013-08-04 11:27:11+0300 [app] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 />
        {'TEXT in td 1': [u'', u'TEXT in td 1'],
         'TEXT in td 2': [u'August 04'],
         'TEXT in td 6': [],
         'TEXT in td 5': [],
         'TEXT in td 4': [],
         'TEXT in td 6': []}
2013-08-04 11:27:11+0300 [app] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 />
        {'TEXT in td 1': [u'', u'TEXT in td 1'],
         'TEXT in td 2': [u'August 04'],
         'TEXT in td 6': [u'TEXT in td 6'],
         'TEXT in td 5': [u'TEXT in td 5'],
         'TEXT in td 4': [u'TEXT in td 4'],
         'TEXT in td 6': [u'TEXT in td 6']}
```

Comment: If you could edit your question to include your full spider code (and the website being crawled) then it will be much easier to us to help out. :)

Answer (score 1):

This probably would be done as follows ( I don't have scrapy, but there is a problem with your Xpaths)

```
 item['TEXT in td 1'] = app.select('//table/tr[1]/td[1]//text()').extract()
 item['TEXT in td 2'] = app.select('//table/tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
 item['TEXT in td 3'] = app.select('//table/tr[2]/td[1]/text()').extract()
 item['TEXT in td 5'] = app.select('//table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract()
 item['TEXT in td 4'] = app.select('//table/tr[3]/td[1]/text()').extract()
 item['TEXT in td 6'] = app.select('//table/tr[3]/td[2]/text()').extract()
```

What we are doing is (assuming a single table) we are fetching each row of the table (**observe tr[1], tr[2] etc.** and then accessing the cells within these rows **observe td[1], td[2] etc..**.

Comment: Thanks, Prahalad! Not work correctly. I have multiple tables on the same source code, now draw from all tables in a single item.

Comment: @Floriano In that case you got to user subscripts with the *table** too just as we have done with **tr** and **td**.

Comment: My problem is how to extract texts 1, 2 and 3. I try it:
**item['TEXT in td 1'] =  app.select('//td[2]/img/@src/text()').extract())** but I don't know how extract. I read on google how to extract.

Comment: Thanks Prahalad, I have included **/ / * table in XPATH**, I did as you said with **tr** and **td** but all of **td text** is extracted in a single item. How can I do?

Comment: If it is possible, can you include the complete scraping source code and the website you are trying to scrape? Also, please paste the output you are obtaining currently.

Comment: My code spider.py is too long by 450 characters. Where can I post code spider.py maybe someone can see me mistake.